# How to read time from a file without converting

Tags: c++, file-io, ipc

My question is general, but I will explain it using a specific example.

Suppose I need to communicate time between two applications. A simple way is to have one application write the output of `gettimeofday()` (`tv_sec` and `tv_usec`) to a file and let the other app read it. The second app needs to 'convert' the strings in order to get an instance of `timeval`.

Is there any way to avoid the conversion?

Is there a better way to do this than simple file write/read?

Comment: If you use the `::time()` function from the `ctime` (or `time.h`) header, you get it as the number of seconds since the epoch. If you store this, no string parsing / conversion will be required.

Comment: Write the structure to a _binary_ file? Also, read more about [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: tons of ways: pipes, sockets, shared memory etc.

Comment: @jogojapan can you give me an example code please. rmind you that I need to store time into a file and retrive from it. How can I use ::time() or timeval? thanks

Comment: @rahman Just use the code given by Johnsyweb. You can write the `time_t` (which is basically an integer) to file. On the receiving end, you read that from file. If you need `timeval` just create an empty `timeval` object and set its `tv_sec` member to the value stored in the `time_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both processes are on the same machine (or at least on machines of the same architecture), the results of [`std::time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) (from [`<ctime>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctime)) will be [seconds since the Epoch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15), and will not need any conversion:

```
std::time_t seconds_since_epoch = std::time(NULL);
```

Disclaimer: This is not the best method of [ipc](/questions/tagged/ipc) and you will need [**to lock the file**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.file_lock) for reading while it is being written, *etc*. Just answering the question.

---

**Update, following comment.**

If you need to write a `timeval`, perhaps the easiest way is to define `<<` and `>>` operators for `timeval` and write and read these as text to the file (no need to worry about byte-ordering) as-is (with no conversion):

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, timeval const& tv)
{
    return out << tv.tv_sec << " " << tv.tv_usec;
}

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, timeval& tv)
{
    return is >> tv.tv_sec >> tv.tv_usec;
}
```

This will allow you to do the following (ignoring concurrency):

```
// Writer
{
    timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    std::ofstream timefile(filename, std::ofstream::trunc);
    timefile << tv << std::endl;
}

// Reader
{
    timeval tv;
    std::ifstream timefile(filename);
    timefile >> tv;
}
```

If both process are running concurrently, you'll need to lock the file. Here's an example using [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.file_lock):

```
// Writer
{
    timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    file_lock lock(filename);

    scoped_lock<file_lock> lock_the_file(lock);

    std::ofstream timefile(filename, std::ofstream::trunc);
    timefile << tv << std::endl;
    timefile.flush();
}

// Reader
{
    timeval tv;
    file_lock lock(filename);

    sharable_lock<file_lock> lock_the_file(lock);

    std::ifstream timefile(filename);
    timefile >> tv;

    std::cout << tv << std::endl;
}
```

...I've omitted the [`exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/interprocess_exception.html) handling (when the file does not exist) for clarity; you'd need to add this to any production-worthy code.

Comment: I am trying to use your first suggestion before reading more about IPC. but I am not able to do that. Is it possible you kindly give me an example. BTW, I need timeval not time_t coz I need usec element also. thanks for helping out.

Comment: I have to get back to you on this. I should try this myself first. thanks

Comment: I'm glad you've found it to be cool. Note that it is incomplete.

Comment: I am using the non locked version and it is working(at least it seems to be). One important question: When one application only writes, and the other application only reads, do we still need file locking?

Comment: @rahman: Absolutely you do. Think about what could happen should the writer truncate the file and start writing while the reader is part-way through reading.