# How to write to and read from a file simultaneously in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, concurrency, ipc

I need to write two programs `write.cpp` & `read.cpp` to run simultaneously. One of them write(overwrite) to a file and the other one reads from it.

Basically, there is always only one line in the file.

`write.cpp` performs the operation successfully but `read.cpp` doesn't show anything. Using `tail -f` also shows incorrect result.

#### write.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  int i = 70;
  char c;
  while(i <85)
  {
      myfile.open ("example.txt");
      c = i++;
      myfile << c << endl;
      myfile.close();
      sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

#### read.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      sleep(1);
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
}
```

May I know which part of both programs causes the problem and how may I solve it?

Comment: `read.cpp doesnt show anything.` Does it exit? Does it get as far as `myfile.good()`. Does it get past it?

Comment: @StoryTeller Good idea, but it isn't portable.

Comment: @PeterWood yes it exits

Comment: @PeterWood That's a good point.  If the reader starts before the writer has passed at least once through the loop, the `open` in it may fail.

Comment: @rahman It exits without printing anything? Or does it print `Unable to open file`?

Comment: @PeterWood it doesn't print anything. I actually run read 'after' starting 'the write

Comment: @PeterWood, the inclusion of `unistd.h` doesn't imply portability in mind.

Comment: @StoryTeller we need a portable code in the long run. so even unistd.h needs to be worked out later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add some detail to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14971684/78845) to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971546/how-to-read-time-from-a-file-without-converting/14971684#14971684), here is how you could use [Boost's interprocess communication](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/interprocess/interprocess_exception.html) to achieve this if you insist on using a file for [ipc](/questions/tagged/ipc).

A writer may look like this:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/file_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    std::string line, shared_filename = "shared";

    {
        std::ofstream create_shared_file(shared_filename.c_str());
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter some text: ";
        std::cin >> line;

        try
        {
            file_lock lock(shared_filename.c_str());
            scoped_lock<file_lock> lock_the_file(lock);

            std::ofstream shared_file(shared_filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::trunc);
            shared_file << line << std::endl;
            shared_file.flush();
        }
        catch (interprocess_exception const& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding reader:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/file_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/sharable_lock.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    std::string line, shared_filename = "shared";

    for (;;)
    {
        try
        {
            file_lock lock(shared_filename.c_str());
            std::cout << "Waiting for file lock..." << std::endl;
            sharable_lock<file_lock> lock_the_file(lock);
            std::cout << "Acquired file lock..." << std::endl;

            std::ifstream shared_file(shared_filename.c_str());
            shared_file >> line;

            if (line.empty())
            {
                std::cout << "Empty file" << line << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Read: " << line << std::endl;
            }
        }
        catch (interprocess_exception const& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not lock " << shared_filename << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Sleeping..." << std::endl;
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're doing the right thing in the writer, but once you've read to end of file, the input stream becomes unusable until the `fail` condition is set.  The best solution is probably to do exactly what you're doing in the writer: open and close the file each time in the read loop.

Be aware that there will be a moment when the file is empty; when you open the file for writing in the writer, it will be truncated, and if the reader happens to try to read at precisely this moment, it will find an empty file.  (It's no big problem; just be aware of it, maybe skipping the `sleep` if you find an empty line.)

Comment: your suggestion worked, thanks. I just wished there was a way we could avoid closing the file in the read.cpp's loop.

Comment: I got feeling may be you are trying to solve reader/writers problem? If so please do share as their are efficient solution to this problem...

Comment: @rahman Why?  If you were trying the read every couple of milliseconds, I could see the motive, but once per second.  FWIW: however: both when writing and reading, you can seek to the beginning of the file before each operation (`pseek` and `gseek`).  In the case of reading, you'll also have to clear the end of file condition (`clear`).  Independently of performance, considerations, this might be preferable for writing, because it means that the reader will never see an empty file.  It does mean that you'll have to always write the same number of characters, however.

Comment: @JamesKanze Actually yes, writing is going to be every 100 milliseconds, and reading would be about the same. Still if you think 100 milliseconds is ok, please let me know. about pseek and gseek, I will check them out, but do you mean if I use them, I won't have to open&close files repeatedly? what is 'clear'? do you mean I use a '\n' or so? thanks

Comment: @Saqlain I don't know. is there a specific short document that I can read? thanks

Comment: @rahman Please read http://syncgen.projects.cis.ksu.edu/documentation/examples/readerwriter.shtml and see if your problem lie in this category, in your existing solution you are doing a kind of pooling which can be avoided...

Comment: @Rahman it may be worhty to also have a look at http://laser.cs.umass.edu/verification-examples/reader_writer/rw.html

Comment: @rahman Re `pseek`, `gseek` and `clear`, they are member functions of `ostream`, `istream` and `ios_base` (the common base class of `ostream` and `istream`) respectively.  Basically, the first two allow you to change the position of the next read or write, and the third clears any "error" status.  (Note that `istream` considers any failure to read, including end of file, as an error.  And that errors in iostream are sticky: they remain until cleared, and cause any other action to be a no-op.)

Comment: @rahman As for whether opening and closing every 100 milliseconds is acceptable... I'd suggest trying it to see.  But it's somewhere around the limit where I'd start to ask the question.

Comment: @rahman (and @Saqlain) These articles seem to be concerned with in process reading and writing, although you do bring up a worthwhile point.  Small, single reads and writes at the OS level are normally atomic, so if the actual data he is writing is small, and he is careful to flush after each write, it will probably be OK.  Otherwise, he may want to look into some sort of file locking.

Comment: @JamesKanze I think it's `seekp` instead of `pseek`, etc.

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, and `seekg` instead of `gseek`.  Typing too fast.